# How to import database script rather than its backup file in Plesk

Tags: sql-server, plesk

I am trying to host my website through Plesk.
Since I am using MSSQL 2014 and the server version is 2012 so importing database backup file through import dump is not working. that is why I want to import script instead of backup.

Anyone please help me on how to import database script in Plesk.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use myLittleAdmin for this.

Comment: Is it possible that I upload script in myLittleAdmin even if the server version is 2012 and mine is 2014. because when I uploaded my database backup through import dump, there was compatibility error...